# How to get stream url when playing video on WKWebview ios

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am making a web browsing application using WKWebview. When a user plays a video on WKWebview I want to get the stream url of that video and save it. So that users can later play that video with AVPlayer through the stream url without having to use the webview to browse to that video anymore.

is there any way?

Answer (score 2):

When a video get played, this html element `document.getElementsByTagName("video")` will send JS event `onplay`.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play_event

At that moment you can get `src`, is stream url, of that playing video and send a JS message back to your `WKScriptMessageHandler` delegate via
`webkit.messageHandlers`

You can read more here:

> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkscriptmessagehandler

Hope this can give you some hints to continue your work.